# Creating a centred UILabel on a navigation bar and updating that label?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel

Is there a way to have a UILabel centred on top of the navigation bar. I would like the label to say a level number and have it update programatically but I'm not sure how to do this. I'd also like to try and be as cheap on memory as possible.

Thank you in advance for any help :)

Comment: What about title of navigation bar instead of label

Comment: can I constantly update the title?

Answer (score 0):

```
self.navigationItem.title = @"The title";
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
[self.navigationItem setTitle:@"The title"];
```

in order to change the text on the label.